# How to update dataframe column in Spark Scala after join?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Join of two dataframes results into almost 60 columns. Most of them suppose to stay as is, but some require update based on values in other columns. Is there a way to update those columns w/o calculating new, removing the originals and renaming the calculated back?

Simplified example: the revenue in `$"Sales` column from the left dataframe is supposed to be weighted by the `$"Weight` in the join results. Is there an efficient way to make the calculation w/o generating the `$"SalesWeighted` as a new column, dropping the original `$Sales` and re-naming `$SalesWeighted` into `$Sales`?

```
val l = Seq((1, 50), (2, 35), (3, 66))
            .toDF("Id", "Sales")

val r = Seq((1, "Premium", 0.2), (1, "Standard", 0.8), 
            (2, "Premium", 0.4), (2, "Standard", 0.6), 
            (3, "Premium", 0.333), (3, "Standard", 0.333), (3, "Garbage", 0.334))
            .toDF("Id", "Grade", "Weight")

display(l.join(r, Seq("Id")).withColumn("SalesWeighted", $"Sales"*$"Weight")
            .orderBy($"Id", $"Grade"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply name the new column the same as the column to be replaced:

```
l.join(r, Seq("Id")).withColumn("Sales", $"Sales" * $"Weight").
  orderBy($"Id", $"Grade")
```

Or, just use `select`:

```
l.join(r, Seq("Id")).
  select($"Id", $"Grade", $"Weight", ($"Sales" * $"Weight").as("Sales")).
  orderBy($"Id", $"Grade")
```

Comment: I didn't realized the `withColumn` **replaces** original column! It is exactly the solution I was looking for. 

The `select` will generate the answer too, but has two drawbacks: real life scenario will require manually listing many columns and any upstream change will require editing this part of the code too.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Drop** to remove the unnecessary columns

```
val l = Seq((1, 50), (2, 35), (3, 66))
                .toDF("Id", "Sales")

    val r = Seq((1, "Premium", 0.2), (1, "Standard", 0.8), 
                (2, "Premium", 0.4), (2, "Standard", 0.6), 
                (3, "Premium", 0.333), (3, "Standard", 0.333), (3, "Garbage", 0.334))
                .toDF("Id", "Grade", "Weight")

    display(l.join(r, Seq("Id")).withColumn("SalesWeighted", $"Sales"*$"Weight").drop($"Sales")
                .orderBy($"Id", $"Grade"))
```

Comment: Yes, combining `drop` and `withColumnRenamed` works fine: 

`display(l.join(r, Seq("Id")).withColumn("SalesWeighted", $"Sales"*$"Weight").drop($"Sales").withColumnRenamed("SalesWeighted", "Sales").orderBy($"Id", $"Grade"))`

I was just wondering if there is way to do the same in one step instead of 3 (something like R dataframe operations).